# ActiveMQ - How to set "jms.nonBlockingRedelivery" via connection url?

Tags: openshift, activemq-classic

I am using Red Hat's AMQ 6 on OpenShift and consuming messages via Red Hat's EAP. I'm using the AMQ JCA resource adapter 5.11.1.

I want to set [jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=true](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/67256c61b1560127e3a56ba9dede61cad3001f4a/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java#L496).

I can't find this in any of the following docs:

- [Connection Configuration URI](https://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri)
- [Resource Adapter Properties](https://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter-properties)
- [Activation Spec Properties](https://activemq.apache.org/activation-spec-properties)

Can this be set via a URL query parameter?

When I set a wrong value like:

```xml
<config-property name="ServerUrl">tcp://localhost:61616?...&amp;jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=WWWWWWW1
```

The log says:

```
org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQEndpointWorker: Successfully established connection to broker...&jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=WWWWWWW1]
```

I would have expected a complaint e.g. "no boolean," "can't parse," etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `nonBlockingRedelivery` via URL query parameter is supported. You can do so using the `jms.` prefix, e.g. `jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=true`.

The reason you don't see any exception is because the OpenWire JMS client ultimately uses [`Boolean.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) to evaluate `WWWWWWW1` which simply returns `false`.

I [added this](https://github.com/apache/activemq-website/commit/b38f87793e173951f951f33037408fd684a71a93) to [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri).

Comment: can this probably be added in the documentation: https://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri ? I was able to test it OK.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/apache/activemq-website/commit/b38f87793e173951f951f33037408fd684a71a93).